# How do I select a JSONB field into a declared variable. I'm getting a null value

Tags: postgresql

When I use a select into I'm getting a null value

```
SELECT ((payload->>'99')::jsonb)->>'BATCH_ID' into in_batch_id 
  from history where id = table.ID;
```

When I check the value of in_batch_id it is null. I need the value of the jsonb field put into the in_batch_id varible. I'm using postgresql.

```json
{
  "1": {
    "seq": null,
    "doc_id": null,
    "batch_id": "91"
  },
  "2": {
    "seq": null,
    "doc_id": null,
    "batch_id": "91"
    
  },
  "99": {
    "seq": null,
    "doc_id": null,
    "emp_id": null,
    "batch_id": 91
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the `payload` value you are dealing with?

Comment: Could you show us what payload looks like?

Comment: JSON keys are case sensitive: `BATCH_ID` <> `batch_id`

Answer (score 1):

The property value at key `99` is not a string with JSON syntax, but rather simply an object. Do not use `(payload->>'99')::jsonb` to access it, but simply `payload->'99'`.

Also `…->>'BATCH_ID'` is wrong when the property is actually named `batch_id` - case is significant in JSON. So use `…->>'batch_id'` instead.

```
SELECT payload->'99'->>'batch_id' INTO in_batch_id 
FROM history
WHERE id = table.ID;
```